# Rectangular pulse coming as trapezoid in Simulink

Tags: pulse, simulink

I have implemented a mechanism where I am feeding a rectangular pulse train to a multiport switch which should give a switching sequence of rectangular pulses. However, I am getting the profile of the pulses as trapezoidal.
Solver Selection:
[image]
Is this because of the 'Fixed-Step' Solver (ode4-Runge-Kutta)?
[image]
function block input:
[image]
The output of function block:
(The code is written so V takes either 1 or 3 values)
[image]

Not sure why it's coming trapezoidal.

The output of Multiport switch:
[image]
Should be a rectangular pulse, but coming trapezoidal.

What can be done in this case?

Comment: There is no such thing as a square wave, except in ideal simulations. Simulink shows you a finite risetime. You can set that risetime to as little as you like, but the simulation will demand that it's finite, rather than zero.

Comment: I am not familiar with this software. But, there is no such thing as a perfectly square signal. Such a thing, if it existed, would require an infinite bandwidth and be comprised of infinite frequencies, so is impossible.  The slope of the transitions seem to take about 10µs, is this too slow?  Note that 10µs corresponds to 10e-6 step size (10e-6 is 10µ).  If you need it faster, try 10e-9.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect it is normal to interpolate between quantum outputs using the computation time with a fixed slew rate of solving the stochastic differential equation rather than a comparator with an infinite slew rate.

In the physical realm, this is equivalent to transferring a charge between low resistive sources and some capacitance in the switch. Thus approximating it as dV/dt=Ic/C.